# Express.js - can find my route

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch-api

I'm using `react.js` and `express.js` and getting 404 error on my `fetch` request.

I'm simply trying to have my routes return `testing express.js...`

**[app.js]**

```
'use strict';

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

const next = require('next');
const express = require('express');
const api = require('./api');

const client = next({ dev: NODE_ENV === 'development' });
const clientHandler = client.getRequestHandler();
const app = express();

client.prepare().then(() => {
  app.use('/api', api);
  app.get('*', (req, res) => clientHandler(req, res));
});

const listener = app.listen(PORT, err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('listening on port: %d', listener.address().port); //eslint-disable-line
});
```

**[/api/index.js]**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/api/test', function (req, res) {
    res.send('testing express.js...');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**[Body.js]**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Body extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.fetchContacts = this.fetchContacts.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchContacts();
  }

  async fetchContacts() {
        const res = await fetch('/api/test');
    const contacts = await res.json();
    log(contacts);
    this.setState({ contacts });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>hello world!</div>;
  }
}
```

**Question:** Why am I getting a 404 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your `/api/test` route work properly, you need to change this:

```
app.get('/api/test', function (req, res) {
    res.send('testing express.js...');
});
```

to this:

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.send('testing express.js...');
});
```

Your router is already looking at `/api` so when you then put a route on the router for `/api/test`, you were actually making a route for `/api/api/test`.  To fix it, make the above change.

---

Also, your index.js file should not be using an `app` object.  It should be using an `express.Router()` object, though an `app` object is also a router so it might kind of work, but it's not the way it should be done.

Comment: wow I can't believe that lol. I swear I tried that like 3 times... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way to load a react JS file on nodejs, follow this basic (React + NodeJS) guide:

https://blog.yld.io/2015/06/10/getting-started-with-react-and-node-js/#.Wd7zSBiWbyg

Or use "create-react-app" :

https://medium.com/@patriciolpezjuri/using-create-react-app-with-react-router-express-js-8fa658bf892d